# light weight image editor that can support pgm format in linux

Tags: software-recommendation, image-editor

Is there any light weight image editor that can support *.pgm format in linux?

any suggestions would be appreciated.

I have used gimp but it's too big size.

Answer (score 1):

**Krita**

It's in universe ubuntu repos and is lighter than gimp. I recommend.

Comment: I saw your comment in the answer and removed it from answer because that is not the place. However This page says inkscape can do http://fileinfo.com/extension/pgm

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to install this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on AskUbuntu.)

Answer (score 0):

#### Inkscape

Inkscape which seems to support .pgm extension (disclaimer: I haven't tested it). Install it with

```
sudo apt install inkscape
```

#### Netpbm

[This page](http://fileinfo.com/extension/pgm) reports that `netpbm` can be a cli solution for *.pgm extensions too. Try it. This is the [homepage of Netpbm](http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: far away to be light weight